# SBRM/RAII for std::va_list/va_start()/va_end use

Tags: c++, raii, variadic-functions

My code contains snippets like these:

```
    std::va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, msgfmt);
    snprintf_buf buf;
    const tchar * msg = buf.print_va_list(msgfmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
```

These are short and `va_start()` and `va_end()` are close together so they are not much of a problem. Exceptions from calls in between the two could be a problem (or not?).

Simple test shows that calling `va_start()` from a function without ellipsis is not allowed. Is calling `va_end()` from a different function than `va_start()` was called from allowed or not?

Basically, I am curious if it is possible to use the SBRM/RAII idiom for these calls, even if it were necessary to call `va_start()` manually and then to pass instance of `std::va_list` into my RAII/SBRM guard instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The specification of `va_start` and `va_end` requires that:

> Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros
>   shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro **in the same
>   function**.

Therefore, `va_end` must be in the variadic function itself, not a class destructor.

Comment: @wilx: The C99 standard, 7.15.1/1.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible implementations assumes std::va_list = char* and va_end() is just setting that pointer to null. Of cause, it can be called outside of function. But I'm not sure, that it will works similar on other platforms.

Better to wrap this functions with a class.