# What is the appropriate way to pass given vararg parameter to another function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, event-handling, variadic-functions

I've begun works on a hook/event system in C++. This system is supposed to handle all sorts of events as notified by other parts of the application.

The issue I've faced is with the way I want it to run.
Generally, I want it to be so that you call a specific function with all arguments you wish to pass on, and then that function handles calling all registered hooks of that specific event, passing them on the arguments, retrieving their result values and returning it to the original caller.

Generally, this is how it was supposed to look:

```
CHookReturn* bInitializationStatus = Hook::Run("Initialize", gGame);
```

```
CHookReturn* bThinkSuccessful = Hook::Run("Think");
```

However, I ran into one issue.
I set it up in such way that the `Run` function in the Hook namespace, calling the Run function of the CHookData_t structure, needs to pass on varargs. I couldn't find any other way. This is how it ended up:

```
union CHookReturn
{
    const char* m_pszValue;
    int m_iValue;
    float m_flValue;
    double m_dlValue;
    bool m_bValue;
};

struct CHookData_t
{
    virtual void Run(CHookReturn* ret, ...) = 0;
};

namespace Hook
{
    std::unordered_map<const char*, std::unordered_map<const char*, CHookData_t*>> umHookList;

    bool Add(const char*, const char*, CHookData_t*);
    bool Exists(const char*, const char*);
    bool Remove(const char*, const char*);
    int Count(const char*);
    CHookReturn* Run(const char*, ...);
};
```

CPP file segment of the Hook::Run function:

```
CHookReturn* Hook::Run(const char* eventName, ...)
{
    // FIXME: Look into alternative execution.
    // This code seems more like a workaround
    // than what I originally wanted it to be.

    int count = Hook::Count(eventName);
    CHookReturn* returnValues = new CHookReturn[count];
    int c = 0;

    unordered_map<const char*, CHookData_t*>::iterator itr;
    unordered_map<const char*, CHookData_t*> res;
    res = umHookList.at(eventName);

    va_list valist;
    void* args;
    va_copy(args, valist);

    for (itr = res.begin(); itr != res.end(); itr++)
    {
        CHookReturn returnData;
        itr->second->Run(&returnData, args);

        returnValues[c] = returnData;
        ++c;
    }

    return returnValues;
}
```

The above code brings up two warnings which make me question if it is a good idea to execute it in this way, as well as whether there are any alternatives I should look into.

The warnings I received were:
`Warning    C6001   Using uninitialized memory 'valist'.`
`Warning    C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'returnValues':  the writable size is 'count*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written.`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use C++11? In case: what about using modern C++ variadic template features instead of old C variadic functions?

Comment: Do you have to use the old school C variadic functions?  C++11's variadic templates make this a lot easier and type safe.  Oh wait, it's a virtual function.  That wont work since you can't have virtual function templates :(

Comment: I tried using C++11's variadic templates but I kind of fucked it up no matter how I tried doing it, so I thought it's not applicable. Perhaps I just made a mistake. And, yeah, the issue is the virtual function.

Comment: I strongly suggest to follows the variadic template way: maybe it's a little difficult at start (but less difficult than old C way, IMHO) but it's very, very powerful.

Comment: As I said, it's kind of impossible with the virtual functions standing in the way. There's no real way to depreciate them in this system I've been making, unfortunately.

Comment: There are a number of approaches of solving the integration between templates and virtual functions. It's a broad topic that falls under the general category of type-erasure. By erasing the template type, in some form or fashion, it becomes possible to implement the templates via a virtual function call. Like I said, it's a rather broad topic. For more information, see your C++ book.

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you describe how the API should be used I'm sure in 5 minutes someone will provide you a nice and clean implementation with variadic template. Problem is we can't "unwind" what it suppose to do based on this C style code.

Comment: And problem with your code is that you didn't use [va_start](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) and without it `va_copy` can't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your code using `va_list`:

```cpp
struct CHookData_t
{
    virtual ~CHookData_t() {}
    virtual void Run(CHookReturn* ret, va_list arg) = 0;
};

namespace Hook
{
    using HooksList = std::unordered_map<
         std::string, 
         std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<CHookData_t>>;

    HooksList umHookList;
    ...
}

std::vector<CHookReturn> Hook::Run(const std::string& eventName, ....)
{
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, eventName);

    auto result = Hook::RunVarg(eventName, valist);

    va_end(valist);

    return result;
}

std::vector<CHookReturn> Hook::RunVarg(const std::string& eventName, va_list arg)
{
    int count = Hook::Count(eventName);
    std::vector<CHookReturn> returnValues(count);

    size_t c = 0;
    for (auto& item : umHookList.at(eventName))
    {
        va_list arg_copy;
        va_copy(arg_copy, arg);
        item.second->Run(&returnValues[c], arg_copy);
        va_end(arg_copy);
        ++c;
    }

    return returnValues;
}
```

I have no idea what are arguments of `Hook::Run` what `va_list` points to, so I can't you provide nice C++ solution.

Note that `va_copy` is needed inside of loop, since some compilers (don't remembered which, possibly msvc) `va_list` behaves like a pointer and reading arguments from it will have impact on each iteration. On other compilers `va_list` behaves like a value and `va_copy` do not change anything.

**offtopic**: your code is to much C, you shouldn't use `const char*` but `std::string` or `std::string_view` if you are using C++17, instead `va_args` it would be better to use variadic template or `std::initializer_list`, avoid raw pointers in favor of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. I've tweaked your code a bit to cover that.
Also `Hook` should not be a `namespace`, by the look of functions and variables it contains it should be a class, so you should fix it too.

Comment: I am keeping it as a namespace instead of making a class without V-table to just act as a 'static class'. I also found Singletons to be quite a pain, which is why I went with this approach. It might be important to note I've also been trying to keep away from the standard library as much as possible.

Comment: I've fixed missing `va_end`, sadly you can't use RAII for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142273/1387438